# What is the total number of combinations in those numeric groups?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, numerical-methods, education, number-systems

Extremely basic question that still confuses me but I would just like to make sure that my understanding is correct. Let's say we have 5 groups:

- Group1
- Group2
- Group3
- Group4
- Group5

In **EACH** of those groups are EXACTLY two numbers:

- 1
- 2

I would like to find out how many combinations in total are possible if I want to have listed every single combination? Is the correct answer 3125 (meaning 5*5*5*5*5)? Example how combinations could look like as per each group (very few examples):

- 1,1,2,1,2
- 1,2,1,1,1
- 2,1,1,2,2
- 1,2,2,2,2
- 2,1,1,1,2
- 1,2,2,2,1
- 1,1,1,1,1
- 1,1,1,2,2

and **many more**, I could be writing those all possible combinations all day long.

I do NOT need from you to list me all possible combinations. Definitely not. All I'm asking is how do I calculate total number of possible combinations? Is correct answer 3125 possible combinations? The reason why I'm note sure about that is in that number (3125) I'm using just total numbers of groups but I'm not defining anywhere that each group has exactly two possibilities (two numbers: 1 and 2). Thank you in advance!

Comment: $2\times 2\times 2\times 2\times 2= 32$

Comment: I don't get what's the difference of you 5 groups. In your example it seems you jus want to Know how many possible combinations of tow numbers on 5 places? then how did you come up with $3125=5^5$